# how to run carrot_planner on stage

Tags: ros, simulation, carrot-planner, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build the package under the sandbox named carrot_plan.
when I run the package shows the results as :

administrator@cpr-det-01:~$ rosrun carrot_plan carrot_plan

%!PS

%%Creator: Eitan Marder-Eppstein (Willow Garage)

%%EndComments

%Insertion Time: 0.004618883

%Footprint calc: 0.000008106

%Illegal footprint

showpage

%%EOF

I saw the  (Willow Garage). Then I run the world file first then run the carrot_plan, but still got the same results.

Anyone can tell me how I can run the carrot_plan on the stage.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61772/how-to-run-carrot_planner-on-stage/) by [TomIGVC](https://answers.ros.org/users/4788/tomigvc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error suggests that the footprint of your robot is inadaquately defined or improperly defined.  You should check how that is defined and make sure it's defined correctly.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0